# Diferenciar lista de itens mostrados na View utilizando "Individual User Account" Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Não tenho muita prática em programação e estou criando um sistema de cadastro de itens como filmes, livros, games, etc. para um trabalho da faculdade. O problema é que preciso utilizar um sistema de gerenciador de usuário para que na view index de cada tipo de item mostre somente aquilo que o usuário cadastros, por exemplo:

João cadastrou em sua lista de filmes "Os Infiltrados" e "Clube da Luta";
José cadastrou em sua lista de filmes "Harry Potter" e "O Senhor dos Anéis".

Quando João efetuar o login deverá somente apresentar os filmes cadastrados por ele, do mesmo jeito que quando José efetuar login deverá apresentar somente os filmes cadastrados por ele.

Criei o projeto utilizando "Individual User Account".

Alguém saberia me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projetos com "Individual User Accounts" vêm com o ASP.NET Identity instalado por padrão. Para fazer o que deseja, suas entidades devem ser modeladas contendo o seguinte:

```
public class Filme
{
    [Key]
    public int FilmeId { get; set; } // Essa é a chave primária.
    public String UsuarioId { get; set; } // Essa é a chave estrangeira, obrigatória.

    // Coloque o resto dos campos aqui

    public virtual ApplicationUser Usuario { get; set; } // Esta linha é a mais importante, 
                                                         // determinando que um filme pertence
                                                         // a um usuário.
}
```

Ao salvar um registro, registre o usuário atual como sendo o "dono" do registro.

```
filme.UsuarioId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Ao ler registros, selecione pelo usuário logado:

```
var usuarioId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var filmes = db.Filmes.Where(f => f.UsuarioId == usuarioId).ToList();
```

Uma forma elegante de trazer os objetos vinculados ao usuário é mudar a classe `ApplicationUser` para o seguinte:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    // Coloque aqui campos que você quer que o usuário tenha.

    public virtual ICollection<Filme> Filmes { get; set; }
}
```

No *Controller* faça assim:

```
var usuarioId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var usuario = db.Usuarios.Include(u => u.Filmes).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UsuarioId == usuarioId);

var filmes = usuario.Filmes.ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, consegui entender o processo e estou aplicando no meu projeto. Teria como ser mais específico onde eu aplico a parte de "Ler registros" e em qual método eu coloco a parte do Controller. Obrigado!!

Comment: "Ler registros" normalmente fica dentro de uma *Action* `Index` ou semelhante. Não sei se você está usando *Scaffolding* ou fazendo tudo manual, mas o Visual Studio gera todo esse código clichê pra você. A parte do *Controller* também vai no mesma *Action* `Index`. Apenas fiz como abordagem alternativa.

Comment: Estou usando o Scaffolding sim. Beleza, vou tentar aqui... Valeu mesmo pela ajuda!!